# How to use regex in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to filter out those with `field not like '%_[0-9]+'` ,

but it turns out that MySQL doesn't take it as regex,

is that possible in MySQL?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That happens because of LIKE is not supposed to accept regular expression as a parameter. There is [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) for such things

```
WHERE field NOT REGEXP '%_[0-9]+'
```