# Find Numeric Values after a specific Text in a String in SQL HIVE DATABASE

Tags: sql, regex, hive

Is it possible to use a regexp function to identify the numeric value after a certain string of text - within one field?

examples of my values within COL_A are TAX_NO 1234567890, -  I would like to match on any values where TAX_NO is present, but I would also like to bring back the number that follows also - the result should be TAX_NO 1234567890.

Which is easy enough as a LIKE '%TAX_NO&', but the problem is that we could have other characters in this field that would read: TAX_NO 1234567890 2 apple street, also occasions where it could be TAX_NO1234567890 2 apple street -

how can I extract just that TAX_NO and the 10 digit number that follows?

Ideally this will be used to match on, using a reference file where TAX_NO 1234567890 is correct and will match against another dataset where this value could be in a number of fields as mentioned with additional text.

Data Sample:

```
COL_A                                - DESIRED RESULT

TAX_NO 1234567890 MR SMITH           - TAX_NO 1234567890  
1/ TAX_NO 1234567890                 - TAX_NO 1234567890  
TAX_NO1234567890 2 APPLE ST          - TAX_NO 1234567890  
MR SMITH TAX_NO 1234567890           - TAX_NO 1234567890  
SMITH TAX_NO 1234567890 2 APPLE      - TAX_NO 1234567890
```

tia

Dan

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: thought I did - apologies, updated

Comment: Add a data sample (5-10 rows) and the requested result, both in a table form.

Comment: If you can, you should reorganize the database so that TAX_NO is a different field from its counterpart. That would be the correct solution. Otherwise, take a look at these questions (depending on your SQL database): [SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928378/using-regex-in-sql-server), [MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067343/how-to-use-regex-in-mysql). Not sure if you're using a different database as you haven't specified.

Comment: Is it always 10 digits? Is there a space missing in your 3rd example?

Comment: Hi Dudu, yes as per the example it could have a space missing, just to add complexity to the subject.