# Comparing List of regex to a string

Tags: mysql

i have question i don't know better approach to do it in mysql. I have a table in mysql with list of regex's each regex represent a company order number

i want to be able to compare a number to that list to get which company this number belongs to. the lazy way is to list all the regex in php and then using loop to get the company , but i want to do this using the power of mysql .

Like @Mech mention this might be vague.

i will try to explain it more :

I have two tables table with actual regex pattern in plain text in a column like "^[8]{1}[0-9]{10}$"

and this pattern belong to a company , there is more than 500 regex patterns .

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is very vague. It sounds as though you want to use the LIKE clause. 
Assuming this to be the case, you can try. SELECT * from foo WHERE company_id LIKE '%regex_id%'

Comment: Thank you @Mech , i have updated the question , i have a plain text regex pattern in a table and each pattern belong to a company. i want use mysql to compare it to a number using Mysql regex to get the company

Comment: +1 for the update. With that regex, is this more suited to your needs? SELECT * from foo WHERE company_id REGEXP "^[8]{1}[0-9]{10}$"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use regex in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067343/how-to-use-regex-in-mysql)

Comment: Thank you @Mech I will give you another example. i have this company order number 00340434317801494748 and i want to compare it with a list of regex that are listed in the a table called regex_companies that contains regex for example ^[8]{1}[0-9]{10}$ si i am searching for some kind of select * from regex_companies

Comment: Np. Give this a try :) SELECT * FROM regex_companies WHERE regex_id IN (SELECT company_id from foo WHERE company_id REGEXP "^[8]{1}[0-9]{10}$")

Comment: this might help you understand this is a regex table looks like https://i.imgur.com/yuNCd0X.png as you can see there is multiple patterns in the table , each entry is related to company , i am looking for a function or procedure to search for each number

Answer (score 1):

Here you go @BM2ilabs. A function as requested :)

```
carrierID(88888141234);

function carrierID($ordernum) {
// create a connection to your db here

// fetch data needed for loop
$sql = "SELECT regex, carrier_id FROM `company_tbl_from_image`";
// fetch results
$results = $conn->query($sql);

// loop through $results
foreach ($results as $result) {
    // individually check against each regex in the table
    $regex = $result[regex];
    // find first instance of $regex, where the $ordernum is unique, there should only be one match
    if (preg_match('/'.$regex.'/', $ordernum)) {
        $carrier_id = $result[carrier_id];
        break; // remove break to show other matches
    }
}
// check if $carrier_id is empty
if ($carrier_id <> "") {
    echo $carrier_id;
} else {
    echo "No carrier ID found.";
}
```

}

Comment: So you basically need to do this in php

Comment: This was based on your mentioning "function". See my other answer for a MySQL only alternative.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL only option. Just search this:

```
SELECT carrier_id FROM `company_tbl_from_image` WHERE 'order number' REGEXP regex
```